# How to trigger a function before Gunicorn starts it's main process

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I'm setting up a Flask app with Gunicorn in a Docker environment.

When I want to spin up my containers, I want my Flask container to create database tables (based on my models) if my database is empty. I included a function in my wsgi.py file, but that seems to trigger the function each time a worker is initialized. After that I tried to use server hooks in my gunicorn.py config file, like below.

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from setup import init_database

def on_starting(server):
    """Executes code before the master process is initialized"""
    init_database()


def max_workers():
    """Returns an amount of workers based on the number of CPUs in the system"""
    return 2 * cpu_count() + 1


bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
worker_class = 'eventlet'
workers = max_workers()
```

I expect gunicorn to trigger the on_starting function automatically but the hook never seems to trigger. The app seems to startup normally, but when I try to make a request that wants to insert a database entry it says that the table doesn't exist. How do I trigger the on_starting hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my issue by preloading the app first before creating workers to serve my app. I did this by adding this line to my `gunicorn.py` config file:

```
...
preload_app = True
```

This way the app is already running and can accept commands to create the necessary database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn imports a module in order to get at `app` (or whatever other name you tell Gunicorn the WSGI application object lives at). During that import, which happens before Gunicorn starts directing traffic to the app, code is executing. Put your startup code there, after you've created `db` (assuming you're using SQLAlchemy), and imported your models (so that SQLAlchemy will know about then and will hence know what tables to create).

Alternatively, populate your container with an pre-created database.

Comment: I already tried something similair by inserting my `init_database` function in my wsgi.py file. But when I do that, my workers simultaneously execute my init_database function which gives me unique constraint errors. A simple if-else statement to check if the tables are already created doesn't work, because the function runs asynchronous.